# Fastest way to make money in GTA IV multiplayer?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I've been reading a lot about money-making schemes in GTA IV multiplayer, and everyone seems to believe something different works best. What is the one mathematically fastest way to make money?

Assume the player has access to the main game, The Ballad of Gay Tony and The Lost and The Damned DLC packs. Try to avoid answers that require boosters (people who are willing to help you specifically gain money), since they're few and far between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running Hangman's NOOSE over and over again with a solid group of people who know how the situation plays out exactly and can communicate is a great way to earn money. You can run NOOSE with random players, but if you aren't winning every time and doing so in just a few minuets the rate at which you earn money isn't as high as it could be. The OP might consider this a "boosting" answer since the money gained is higher when working with a group of well coordinated players, if so just disregard it.

I'd still say that Hangman's NOOSE is the best way though, because when it goes well you win rather quickly, and when things go bad, your group is killed rather quickly. The other forms of multiplayer (DM/TDM/Racing/Turf Wars/ect) can take much longer and don't return nearly as much money.

Just be warned if you are looking to get the Wanted achievement/trophy. The grind to it ($5,000,000 gained in multiplayer) will take forever no matter which method you end up using.

Answer (score 2):

I would say find the right game type for yourself. The reason people have different methods that are the best according to them is because they found a way that works well for their play style. It all depends on what aspect of the game you are good at. If your good at shooting, choose a shooting game type, if your good at driving choose a racing game type, etc. The money needed to hit the highest level is a lot so find something your comfortable with and do it!

Comment: I'm looking for a mathematically proven answer - the most possible amount of money in the shortest possible amount of time. It's assumed that the player is reasonably good at all game types.

Comment: Your skill * Time played = Moneys.

But seriously, an equation that calculates point gain in a game will always have a variable tied to your skill and you also have to factor in luck/chance. It's impossible to have an equation with all finite variables when talking about gaining game points, unless you are looking for a method that involves cheating to gain points, in which case you should re-title this question, "Cheating whores: I want to be like you, teach me your ways!"

Comment: That's not necessarily true. I could use the same skill level for the same amount of time on different game modes, and get a different amount of money for it. There are over a dozen different modes of multiplayer in GTA IV - I'm looking for the fastest way to make money, using a given strategy, in a given game mode. I'm not looking for cheats, only optimal efficiency.

Comment: that's my point exactly. Your assuming skill level to be the same on all game types, but no one can say for certain that you will make more points on a game type than another because no one has the same skill level on all game types. It would be in general, you make more points in a certain game type *IF* you have the same skills as the person answering the question.

Comment: What your looking for is a chart of some sort that gives averages of all game types. With that you can rule out the *IF* your this specific person. It would just be in general, if you play this game type, you will make the most money in the shortest amount of time. Again that's not a for certain thing. its a best guess. Unfortunately i don't think a chart like i described exists :(

Comment: That's the whole point - I don't expect you to know the subtle differences in my skills, but a chart of averages / best guesses will give me a starting point. A chart like that indeed doesn't exist yet, which is why I'm asking the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Real Easy to get this with Boosters. There are two websites (hint: search 360 achievements and true achievements) that run lots and lots of boosting sessions (For any xbox game) all the time. I'll let you find them yourself, it's not too hard at all.

What you wanna do is use the Happiness island rubber banding method. So that means little effort from you and your boosting partner and getting approx 150k - 160k an hour for the shooter, and 20k for the person dying. Awesome eh?